# List-Unsubscribe header in Microsoft Graph Api is not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, nuget-package, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have added unsubscribe header while sending email via Microsoft Graph API but still it is not adding List-Unsubscriber header in the email.

```
Dim HeaderOptions = New List(Of [Option]) From {
                    New HeaderOption("List-Unsubscribe", "<mailto:unsubscribe@example.com?subject=unsubscribe>"),
                    New HeaderOption("priority", "High")
                    }

graphClient.Users(FromEmail).SendMail(objMessage, True).Request(HeaderOptions).PostAsync().Wait()
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Never to late.

To include `List-Unsubscribe` mail header, you need to add it via [SingleValueExtendedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
using Microsoft.Graph.Me.SendMail;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "johndoe@contoso.com",
                },
            },
        },
        SingleValueExtendedProperties = new List<SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty>
        {
            new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
            {
                Id = "String 0x1045",
                Value = "<mailto:unsubscribe@reply.contoso.com>, <https://contoso.com/notifications/unsubscribe/123>",
            },
        },
    },
};
```

If you need to include also `List-Unsubscribe-Post`, the solution is more complicated, because there is no way to add `List-Unsubscribe-Post` via `SingleValueExtendedProperties`. You need to send message in MIME format.

Great blog post how to create a MIME message for Graph API is [here](https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2021/08/sending-mimemessage-via-microsoft-graph.html)

Answer (score 0):

The header options that you are using are intended for adding HTTP headers to the HTTP request.  I believe the header you are trying to add is actually an Email message header.  To add these you should use the [InternetMessageHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/internetmessageheader?view=graph-rest-1.0) property on the [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) object itself.

Comment: when I am using Internetmessageheader to set the UNSUBSCRIBE header it is giving me following error...


{"Code: InvalidInternetMessageHeader
Message: The internet message header name 'List-Unsubscribe' should start with 'x-' or 'X-'. Inner error
"}

Comment: Interesting.  That seems broken to me.  I'll see if I can find the right person to talk to about this.  According to this https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml there should be no x- prefix.

Comment: Anyone having any solution to this? This is a core requirement for us to have unsubscribe header.

Comment: @SheerazAhmed I followed up internally on this and unfortunately, someone chose to disallow adding headers without the 'x-' prefix.  I am working to get this resolved.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing from you @darrel. Thanks.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, any progress on this?  The `References` and `In-Reply-To`-headers are something we are looking to add and were possible according to https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/869

Comment: @Zombaya  Sorry, no updates yet.  I'm on vacation this week. I'll follow up next week.

Comment: @Zombaya  I have received general agreement that this constraint is not required.  Now we just have to find out how to get it onto the right person's backlog.

Comment: @DarrelMiller this issue is affecting us, as well. Thanks for your help chasing it down. Any update on getting it fixed? Thanks.

Comment: I have not been able to make much progress.  I would recommend creating a uservoice request on our new Microsoft Graph uservoice as that will get the team's attention https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks, Darrel. I have just created this UserVoice request. Upvotes welcome: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37872061-allow-internet-message-headers-that-are-not-prefix

Comment: It is still not working and I've raised an issue in GitHub: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2105

Comment: @RaymondTang check my answer if it will help you

Comment: @user2250152 yes I've been using that solution for a few months now. I also used this message header too: new InternetMessageHeader { Name = "X-List-Unsubscribe", Value = listUnsubscribe }